# Html select option selected does not work

Tags: html, combobox

How to set default selected element in combobox? Neither of the following worked for me:

Version 3:

```
<select id="parent">
    <option value='null'>(Root)</option>
    <option selected='yes' value='/'>Main</option>
</select>
```

Version 2:

```
<select id="parent">
    <option value='null'>(Root)</option>
    <option selected='true' value='/'>Main</option>
</select>
```

Version 1:

```
<select id="parent">
    <option value='null'>(Root)</option>
    <option selected value='/'>Main</option>
</select>
```

In all cases first option is selected on page, not that one which is marked selected.

**SOME OTHER DETAILS**

(1)

Page source beginning follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        ...
```

(2)

Browser is Firefox 13.0.1

Comment: All versions work: http://jsfiddle.net/AYzxV/ so the problem is in some part of the code that was not disclosed. Version 1 is one that conforms to the HTML 4.01 specification; others just happen to work, too.

Comment: All versions do not work, believe me. If you need some other parts of code then ask for them.

Comment: No need for beliefs here; check out my jsfiddle. You need to post an example that demonstrates the problem. The code posted so far does not.

Comment: I saw your link. But I need not it works there, I need it works on my site. I know all this mess about compliance. The question is why it does not work. What extra information you need to judge about the reason? If I isolate the the problem, I would not ask the question here.

Comment: If you cannot present a reproducable problem, you should not ask here.

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask you about this, mister.

Comment: Hi @SuzanCioc, you might wanna check out mercurial's and user25794 answers. those might be the answer to your problem (at least they were for mine)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `selected` to the option you want to be selected by default.
Check the following example taken from [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select).

```
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="choice">
  <option value="first">First Value</option>
  <option value="second" selected>Second Value</option>
  <option value="third">Third Value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The syntax `selected="selected"` is the XHTML syntax, but mere `selected` works just as well and is correct per HTML 4.01. BTW, if you give references, refer to reliable sources, not w3schools.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela this is a good reference http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/selected but it says it is HTML, I am confused now

Comment: @ajax333221, `selected="selected"` is *allowed* in HTML 4.01 (and in previous versions) too, just needlessly verbose. And in practice, `select` with *any* value works; the value is ignored, it’s the presence of the attribute name that matters.

Answer (score 36):

I'm just going to throw this out there because it has driven me crazy on more than one occasion:

When you refresh (F5) a page, Firefox preserves the selected values of any <select> elements on the page.

So if you're like me and write the select menu, load the page to make sure it works, then add the "selected" attribute, and refresh the page to make sure the selected one appears ... it won't (in Firefox, anyway).

Reloading the page entirely by clicking in the Address field and pressing Enter does honor the "selected" attribute.

Comment: Is there any workaround except reloading? (in Firefox)

Comment: THANKS! Appreciate this is an old answer but it helped me so confirming this is still the behaviour in Firefox 108.0.2

Comment: I wish I found your solution ~an hour ago... Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Maybe the autocomplete form attribute is throwing you out.

Try adding autocomplete="off" to the form tag.

This way even when you refresh the page in FF the selected attribute is respected.

GL

Comment: THIS!! I like this!! I'm having the same problem as OP but this is the only answer that works! (for this particular problem) thank you so much!

Comment: +1 This is still an issue. Adding autocomplete="off" does the trick, and clears the previously selected value, as it should.